# Spawning Python Threads at EXACTLY the Same Time?

Tags: python, multithreading, audio

Right now some friends and I are making a program that generates music using square waves in Python (we're still very early on in development). One of the roadblocks along the way was that we figured that PyAudio will only play one sound at a time, and if you tried to play sounds over each other, e.g. to make a chord, the sounds just overwrite each other. Our current strategy is using threading to get around it, and it almost works, but the timing for when the threads start is very slightly off. Here is a snippet of our code that generates a C major chord:

```
import numpy as np
import pyaudio
import math
from scipy import signal
import multiprocessing
from time import time

def noteTest(frequency):
    l = np.linspace(0, 2, 384000, endpoint=False)
    p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
    stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16, channels=1, rate=192000, output=True)
    wave_data = signal.square(2 * math.pi * frequency * l)
    stream.write(wave_data)

def playNotes():
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        multiprocessing.Process(target = noteTest, args = [523.25113060119]).start()
        print(time())
        multiprocessing.Process(target = noteTest, args = [659.25511382575]).start()
        print(time())
        multiprocessing.Process(target = noteTest, args = [783.99087196355]).start()
        print(time())

playNotes()
```

When I look at the output of the program, here are the times it gives:

```
1510810518.870557
1510810518.8715587
1510810518.8730626
```

As you can see, the threads are over a thousandth of a second apart. This is surprisingly noticeable, even for just one chord, but we fear that this will become an even bigger problem if we try and make an actual song as the tracks will drift apart and get out of time with each other. Note that all of the computers we tested this with DO have multiple physical cores. Is there any way to make the threads synchronize better, or are we better off finding an alternate solution?

Comment: The threads will still be kicked off from the single process running the program (even if it is on a different core), so odds are you'll have delays.  What about assuming the threads will have a delayed start, but giving the thread an offset at which time to start playing the specific instrument?  Ie, thread 2 will start later than thread 1, so have thread 1 wait a specific time (after kickoff) to start playing.

Answer (score 1):

An option is to have a delay in each thread, before playing the sound.  If you have a reasonable idea of the offset involved in starting the threads, you can pass that value in as the delay.

For example, let's say there is 1ms delay between starting threads:

- 0ms: Start thread 1, with 1ms delay
- 0ms: Thread 1 starts on new core, waits
- 1ms: Start thread 2, with no delay
- 1ms: Thread 1 starts playing after delay
- 1ms: Thread 2 starts on new core, no delay, and starts playing

Another option, is to have each thread kick off, but wait for a signal from the main process loop to ALL the threads, before they start playing.

Comment: I like that second suggestion, but does multiprocessing provide something for that, or would we need to figure out our own solution to that problem?

Comment: Look into IPC, semaphores, mutexes, etc.  It's a fairly wide field, but there are lots of resources available (outside the scope of the question, unfortunately), and should most certainly be doable with a fair degree of precision.  You'd likely also need to look at process priorities, etc, if timing is extremely crucial.